# Rewriting a trigger in SQL-Server in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql-server, oracle, database-trigger

I created a trigger in SQL server that was designed to act whenever data was entered into a certain table, in this case a table called FORECAST_TEST_DATA. The trigger was to then take certain values from the inserted row and insert them into a table called the PRODUCT_TEST_DATE table. The other columns in the table were then to be filled with values which already existed within the table, using products that shared a common PROD_NUM value.

The query in SQL server, looks as follows:

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER FORECAST_TRIGGER ON FORECAST_TEST_DATA
FOR INSERT
AS
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_TEST_DATA
(PRODUCT_TEST_DATA.PROD_NUM, PRODUCT_TEST_DATA.MONTH, PRODUCT_TEST_DATA.STORE_TYPE, 
PRODUCT_TEST_DATA.PRODUCT_KEY, PRODUCT_TEST_DATA.CATEGORY, 
PRODUCT_TEST_DATA.BRAND_NAME,PRODUCT_TEST_DATA.COLOUR)
SELECT
inserted.PROD_NUM, inserted.MONTH, inserted.STORE_TYPE, inserted.PRODUCT_KEY,
PRODUCT_TEST_DATA.CATEGORY, PRODUCT_TEST_DATA.BRAND_NAME,PRODUCT_TEST_DATA.COLOUR
FROM inserted, PRODUCT_TEST_DATA
WHERE inserted.PROD_NUM = PRODUCT_TEST_DATA.PROD_NUM
GO
```

The trigger already has the desired functionality, it just needs to be rewritten into Oracle SQL.

Thanks for taking the time to read through this problem, any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are you struggling with, specifically?

Comment: Take a swing at converting it, and when you get stuck, paste it (above).  We can help you figure out the rest, but it isn't nice to ask us to do all of the work.  For instance, the docs for Oracle triggers is really easy to find.  It should only take you 10-15 minutes to get really close.

Answer (score 0):

Here is oracle syntax -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER FORECAST_TRIGGER
AFTER INSERT ON FORECAST_TEST_DATA
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_TEST_DATA
(PROD_NUM, MONTH, STORE_TYPE, PRODUCT_KEY, CATEGORY, BRAND_NAME, COLOUR)
SELECT
:new.PROD_NUM, :new.MONTH, :new.STORE_TYPE, :new.PRODUCT_KEY,
:new.CATEGORY, :new.BRAND_NAME, :new.COLOUR
FROM PRODUCT_TEST_DATA
WHERE :new.PROD_NUM = PROD_NUM;
END;
```